# web worker serialization ignores ES5 get/set

Tags: javascript, web-worker

When a web worker serializes data to pas to/from the worker, the following code (typescript):

```
private _spacing:number;
get spacing():number {
    return this._spacing;
}
set spacing(src:number) {
    this._spacing = src;
}
```

will pass across the data _spacing but not spacing. Is there a way to set things so it passes across the property spacing?

Comment: No; you can't serialize a function.

Comment: @SLaks that's what I was afraid of. I understand the get/set is a function pretending to be a variable. I was just hoping that pretend could work for a web worker.

Comment: That would completely break thread safety.

Comment: if you used Object.defineProperty to bind your getter/setters, "spacing" would appear in JSON.stringify as the value of "_spacing". i dunno if TS breaks that, but i use "computed" values in my persisted state all the time as described.

Comment: @dandavis yes _spacing comes across fine. The problem is I want a constructor that handles both the interface (properties only from the web worker postMessage) and the class (copy constructor). At present that is messy because I have to use _spacing and would prefer to use spacing. With that said, this is just a nit.

Comment: @SLaks - I understand not taking methods across. I was hoping that any get would then grab that value and take it across as a literal variable.

Comment: instead of other properties, i always use variables to store getter states, i just find it cleaner and less-repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

There is not, the serialization of values being passed into [`Worker.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker.postMessage) is handled by the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm), according to MDN:

> > Certain parameters of objects are not preserved
> >
> > - The lastIndex field of RegExp objects is not preserved.
> > - Property descriptors, **setters, and getters** (as well as similar metadata-like features) are not duplicated. For example, if an object is marked read-only using a property descriptor, it will be read-write in the duplicate, since that's the default condition.
> > - The prototype chain does not get walked and duplicated.

You might be able to work around this by passing a copy of the object in, manually copying the literal values instead of the getter.